# Get error when importing FuncAnimation from matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't import FuncAnimation from matplotlib.animation. When I try to do it I get the error :

> ValueError: insecure string pickle

I use matplotlib 1.5.1, Python 2.7, Mac OSX 10.11.3 , in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: `from matplotlib import animation`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque got the same error

Comment: When I run `from matplotlib import animation` I still get `ValueError: insecure string pickle`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the problem (for my install):

```
brew install imagemagick
```

I dug into the errors python was showing ...

```
$ python -c "import matplotlib.animation" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 578, in <module>
    class ImageMagickWriter(MovieWriter, ImageMagickBase):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 74, in wrapper
    if writerClass.isAvailable():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 277, in isAvailable
    creationflags=subprocess_creation_flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1334, in _execute_child
    child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 972, in load_string
    raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"
ValueError: insecure string pickle
$
```

And noticed ImageMagick was being used.  Given the comments in this thread ... https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5314#issuecomment-225368342 ... about missing dependencies, I installed ImageMagick and the issue went away.