# Trouble with loading 'FuncAnimation' from matplotlib.animation

Tags: matplotlib, animation, importerror, site-packages

I need to import FuncAnimation from matplotlib.animation, but I am failing with the following error code:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'FuncAnimation' from 'matplotlib.animation' (C:\Users\myName\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py)"

I saw a similar question here, but with a different Error message and the suggested fixes did not work for me. [Get error when importing FuncAnimation from matplotlib.animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546991/get-error-when-importing-funcanimation-from-matplotlib-animation)

I am using anaconda with Matplotlib 3.1.3, Python 3.7 and Spyder 4.0.1 under Windows 10. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: I now tried another, lower Spyder version (Spyder 3.3.6) in a new Anaconda environment while keeping the above mentioned version of Python and Matplotlib. Like this I could import and use FuncAnimation. Does anybody now if this means for shure that the Matplotlib FuncAnimation does not work with Spyder 4, generally? Maybe it could also be an issue of package overloading in my former python environment?!?